# CLang: Running function in std::thread causes BAD_ACCESS on struct creation

Tags: c++, multithreading, clang, exc-bad-access, sctp

I've recently switched from Kubuntu 16.04 to Mac OS High Sierra and started porting parts of the code I work with on a regular basis. Among that is a C++ wrapper library for libsctp-dev.

I'm using the [SCTP kernel extension](https://github.com/sctplab/SCTP_NKE_HighSierra/blob/master/README.md) to have the same SCTP API as on my Linux machine. While the API calls do not make a problem, using threads provided by the standard C++ library seems to make problems now. The problem can be found in the following code snippets:

```
void Server::start(int32_t port) {
    //This allocates the socket with the SCTP protocol assigned
    Receiver::start();
    //This function now binds the desired port to the created socket
    this->_bind(port);

    //Here I register handlers for network events that can occur
    this->notificationHandler.setAssocChangeHandler(std::bind(&Server::handleAssocChange, this, _1));
    this->notificationHandler.setShutdownEventHandler(std::bind(&Server::handleShutdownEvent, this, _1));
    this->notificationHandler.setSendFailedHandler(std::bind(&Server::handleSendFailed, this, _1));

    //This is the interesting part - this will lead to BAD_ACCESS
    //exceptions in the receive function
    dummy = this;
    this->receiveThread = std::thread(dummyReceive);

    //However, if I run it in the same thread, everything works fine
    //(except that I need the receive loop to run in a separate thread)
    //dummyReceive();

    //This is the original call, I just used the dummy function to be
    //sure that the bind function does not create the problem
    //this->receiveThread = std::thread(std::bind(&Server::receive, this));
}
```

This is the part where the dummyReceive function is defined:

```
Server *dummy = NULL;
void dummyReceive(){
    dummy->receive();
}
```

Finally, this is the code of the receive method (Server is a subclass of Receiver, which is in turn a subclass of Endpoint):

```
void Receiver::receive() {

    uint8_t buffer[this->max_buffer_size];
    uint32_t buffer_size = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in peer_addr = {};
    socklen_t peer_addr_size = sizeof(peer_addr);

    struct sctp_sndrcvinfo info = {};
    int32_t flags = 0;

    while (this->can_receive) {
        buffer_size = Endpoint::receive(buffer, max_buffer_size, peer_addr, peer_addr_size, info, flags);
        if (buffer_size == 0) {
            // Notification was sent
        } else if (buffer_size == -1) {
            CERR("Endpoint::receive(...) returned -1" << std::endl);
        } else {
            this->receiveCallback(buffer, buffer_size, peer_addr, peer_addr_size, info);
        }
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that the BAD_ACCESS exception occurs when "peer_addr" gets initialized:

```
struct sockaddr_in peer_addr = {};
```

This is what CLion gives me as an error message:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x70000807bb88)
```

I can avoid this by initializing the "peer_addr" and "info" struct right at the start of the function. However, then the call to "Endpoint::receive" crashes again with a BAD_ACCESS exception. This time with the following parameters:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x70000c4adb90)
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here? I'm using the Xcode toolchain 9.4.1 (which is internally using clang as far as I know) with CMake 3.12.0 (I'm using CLion as an IDE). If anyone needs the full library code I can upload it to git and share a link (currently it is only on a private git server).

Best
Pascal

Comment: what is `max_buffer_size`? is it large enough to cause a stack overflow? you shouldn't allocate large buffers on the stack.

Comment: @Alan: It is ensured by the Endpoint::Receive method that not more than max_buffer_size bytes are written into the buffer. Also the BAD_ACCESS exception is thrown right at the start of the function call (i.e. I cannot even debug into the call of Endpooint::receive)

Comment: a stack overflow is trying to allocate too much on the stack. You're thinking of a stack overrun where writes to the stack occur outside the allocated memory. In my experience OSX is bad at detecting stack overflows and often raises `BAD_ACCESS` instead

Comment: @AlanBirtles: You're a genius! It was the stack overflow due to the buffer allocation on the stack. Thank you so much for the hint! Can I choose your comment to be the solution to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `max_buffer_size` is large you are likely to be encountering a stack overflow.

The stack is a very limited size and is probably smaller on OSX than it was on Linux (e.g. the default pthread stack size is only 512K https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1419/_index.html).

Large buffers should be heap allocated rather than stack allocated.

OSX isn't very good at detecting stack overflows and often raises the confusing `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error instead of a more helpful stack overflow error.